# Loading a baked Plugin Model fails with "Table class for alias Data.History could not be found"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-bake

I baked a model into a plugin, but it fails to load.

### What I did:

1. Baked a model

   ```
   bin/cake bake model History --connection data --plugin Data --no-rules --no-validation --table elements_history
   ```

> One moment while associations are detected.
>
> Baking table class for History...
>
> Creating file /var/www/app/plugins/Data/src/Model/Table/HistoryTable.php
> Wrote `/var/www/app/plugins/Data/src/Model/Table/HistoryTable.php`
>
> Baking entity class for History...
>
> Creating file /var/www/app/plugins/Data/src/Model/Entity/History.php
> Wrote `/var/www/app/plugins/Data/src/Model/Entity/History.php`
>
> Baking test fixture for History...
>
> Creating file /var/www/app/plugins/Data/tests/Fixture/HistoryFixture.php
> Wrote `/var/www/app/plugins/Data/tests/Fixture/HistoryFixture.php`
> Bake is detecting possible fixtures...
>
> Baking test case for Data\Model\Table\HistoryTable ...
>
> Creating file /var/www/app/plugins/Data/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/HistoryTableTest.php
> Wrote `/var/www/app/plugins/Data/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/HistoryTableTest.php`
> Done

2. Loaded the newly created plugin via `$this->addPlugin('Data');`
3. Verified the plugin was loaded via `bin/cake plugin loaded`
4. Confirmed `plugins/Data/src/Model/Table/HistoryTable.php` exists

   ```
   root@debian:/var/www/app# cat plugins/Data/src/Model/Table/HistoryTable.php
   <?php
   declare(strict_types=1);

   namespace Data\Model\Table;

   use Cake\ORM\Query;
   use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
   use Cake\ORM\Table;
   use Cake\Validation\Validator;

   /**
    * History Model
    *
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History newEmptyEntity()
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History get($primaryKey, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
    * @method \Data\Model\Entity\History[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
    *
    * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
    */
   class HistoryTable extends Table
   {
       /**
        * Initialize method
        *
        * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
        * @return void
        */
       public function initialize(array $config): void
       {
           parent::initialize($config);

           $this->setTable('elements_history');
           $this->setDisplayField('id');
           $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

           $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

       }

       /**
        * Returns the database connection name to use by default.
        *
        * @return string
        */
       public static function defaultConnectionName(): string
       {
           return 'data';
       }
   }
   ```
5. [Added the plugin model](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#plugin-models) to an arbitrary controller method:

   - either `$this->loadModel('Data.History');`,
   - or `TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Data.History');`
6. Got the error:

> Table class for alias Data.History could not be found.
> Cake\ORM\Exception\MissingTableClassException
> CORE/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:245

### What have I tried:

- I have looked into `CORE/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php` and I can log that `_getClassName` [receives](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/94e00c263732b0efb63c18f946c76da0b6d96a51/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php#L282) `Data.History`, but returns a `null`. I have also logged `$this->locations` which it loops through, and the plugin path is not there:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Model/Table
  )
  ```
- Added `debug` to `CORE/src/Core/App.php` [right before](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/94e00c263732b0efb63c18f946c76da0b6d96a51/src/Core/App.php#L66) it runs a test for `\Model\Table\HistoryTable` against `_classExistsInBase`.

  ```
  debug([
      '$plugin' => $plugin,
      '$name' => $name,
      '$base' => $base,
      '$fullname' => $fullname,
      '_classExistsInBase' => static::_classExistsInBase($fullname, $base),
  ]);
  ```

  ```
  CORE/src/Core/App.php (line 70)
  [
  '$plugin' => 'Data',
  '$name' => 'History',
  '$base' => 'Data',
  '$fullname' => '\Model\Table\HistoryTable',
  '_classExistsInBase' => false,
  ]
  ```

Do you know what is the issue and how to fix? I'm on CakePHP 4.2.4 and Bake 2.

Comment: Please do not use made up names when it comes to such problems, no matter how sure you are that you didn't made a mistake, there could still be one, and people here would just waste their time.

Comment: are you using a connection other than the default, for that plugin?

Comment: @ndm Ok, no problem, I have edited the question with real data I copied from the console

Comment: @Salines yes, it uses a different datasource, I have pasted the `HistoryTable` source, it has a `defaultConnectionName` method

Comment: Is the plugin's namespace properly mapped in your `composer.json`, and the autoloader dumped accordingly?

Comment: @ndm That was it, thank you. Carefully following [plugins.html#manually-autoloading-plugin-classes](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/plugins.html#manually-autoloading-plugin-classes) has helped. Can you please post this as an answer, so that I can accept and upvote?

Comment: Note to my future self coming back here - remember `routes`: `$this->addPlugin('Data', ['routes' => false]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of manually created plugins you need to make sure that you update your `composer.json`'s autoloader configuration accordingly and dump the autoloader, otherwise your plugin classes cannot be found.

For your local `Data` plugin that would look something like this:

```json
{
    // ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            // ...
            "Data\\": "plugins/Data/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            // ...
            "Data\\Test\\": "plugins/Data/tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

and then you dump the autoloader:

```sh
composer dumpautoload
```

If you create your plugins using bake, it will ask you whether it should modify your `composer.json`, and if you allow it it will update it accordingly and dump the autoloader.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Manually Autoloading Plugin Classes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#manually-autoloading-plugin-classes)**
- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Creating Your Own Plugins > Creating a Plugin Using Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#creating-a-plugin-using-bake)**